# Session key error while updating the page counts?

Tags: django, django-views, django-sessions

Here I am updating the page count in the homepage view but this code is not working properly.

It gives the `IntegrityError` saying `NOT NULL constraint failed: mysite_pagevisit.session`

What might be the reason? How can I solve it ?

```
class HomePageView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        if not PageVisit.objects.filter(session=request.session.session_key):
            PageVisit.objects.create(ip=request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'], session=request.session.session_key)
```

settings

```
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 5  #for test
```

models

```
class PageVisit(models.Model):
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    session = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def total_visits(self):
        return PageVisit.objects.count()
```

Comment: Are you sure that the user is logged in? My guess is that the error is because the user has not logged in and the root cause for `request.session.session_key` being NULL. Try to print `request.session.session_key`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your session key is `None` here. So you need to [`create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/sessions/) one first if it is None. For example:

```
class HomePageView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        if not request.session.session_key:
            request.session.create()
        
        if not PageVisit.objects.filter(session=request.session.session_key):
```

Comment: may I ask how it's possible to not have a session at this point when the request already been through the session middleware?